# tailwind classes not registering when using classNames library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've recently added **Tailwind** to one of my **Next@12.3.4** projects.

So far, everything seems to be working as expected. However, I've noticed that when using the [classNames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library to add classes, Tailwind fails to register and inject them.

```
const Example = () => (
    <span className={classNames(
        // These will work, since they've already been declared in another component without classNames
        "font-bold text-slate-500",
        // This will add the class, but Tailwind will not inject the styles to the page.
        { "text-xs": flag }
    )}>
        Example text
    </span>
);
```

Is there a way around this? I'm trying to avoid using ternary operators inside the className prop, as this tends to get ugly with lots of dependent classNames.

Comment: Do you actually need this import directive - import "@Styles/Global/Tailwind.css";? You have configured tailwindcss following the docs, I presume. I have set up Tailwind on a Nextjs 13 project lately by following this - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs  and it is working fine.

Comment: @CodeBird I couldn't seem to get `globals.css` to work, so my solution was to put the "@tailwind" directives inside of my own `Tailwind.css` file and then import it as shown. Removing the import results in a raw HTML document.
Also, I don't know if it changes anything, but I'm using Next 12 *not* 13.

Comment: Are you sure that if you remove `classNames` it works and`text-xs` is injected? Maybe you forgot to add this file/folder to the `content` tailwind config property?